# Reading Column of Data in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to read a .csv file, match a date in the first column based on input data, then write out the corresponding values in that row from several different columns. The first tier of code is as follows:

```
    dates=[]
    temp=[]

    infile=open('test.csv','r')
    for column in infile:
        info=column.split(",")
        days=info[0]
        Temp24hrMax=info[7]

prompt1=input("Select 'S' to look temperature info for a single day, 'M' for a range of days, or 'Q' to quit. ")
            while prompt1!="Q":
                if prompt1=="S":
                    prompt2=input("Enter the date you would like information for (mm/dd/yyyy). Must be between 1/1/1970 and 10/20/2017. ")
    if prompt2==days:
       dates.append(days)
       temp.append(Temp24hrMax)
       print(dates)
       print(temp)
       prompt1=input("Select 'S' to look for temperature info for a single day, 'M' for a range of days, or 'Q' to quit. ")
```

The code wades through the first if statement correctly, however when a date is entered (format is yyyymmdd), the script only returns the column headers, regardless of the date entered.

Comment: There is a csv module builtin standard API. You should take a look.

Comment: Also, pandas handles csv really well

Comment: If you only get a header, your code is not indented under `for column in infile:` correctly